# Creating XTEXT Grammar from existing Ecore Model

Tags: xtext, ecore

I am trying to generate xtext grammar from existing ecore model. The xtext grammar is generated fine. When I do "Generate xtext artifacts" it ends up with "2278 [main] INFO  .emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow  - Done."

However, it creates errors in project like in "formatter2" saying "type cannot be resolved". Please see below image for details and guide.

[image: Details]

Regards,
Misbah.

Comment: does the missing classes exist (in ZNotationEcore). that the plugin defining them also export the package in manifest and does the mydsl plugin has a dependency to the plugin defining the class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply: POINT1: does the missing classes exist (in ZNotationEcore)...... Yes, thats why they are imported ------ POINT2: that the plugin defining them also export the package in manifest............ I have this entry in manifest "Require-Bundle: ZNotationEcore," -------- POINT3: does the mydsl plugin has a dependency to the plugin defining the class? ..........ZNotationEcore exists under Dependencies ->required plug-ins

Comment: can you please share a complete reproducer (github/gitlab)

Comment: also Require-Bundle: ZNotationEcore, is not the export

Comment: Please see and guide: https://github.com/MisbahAwan/xtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the java classes for the ecore are missing

these java classes are not generated automatically, but you need to trigger the creation manually.

therefore open the genmodel file and do a rightclick generate model code in the root.

Comment: Can you please explain a little...

Comment: I have another question. If I update my ecore model later on, would the change be reflected in my xtext grammar? for example if I add a new class in ecore, would it be included in my DSL grammar? if yes then how?

Comment: you can simply adjust the grammar manually. is there a specific reason to go the hard way for beginners and use a manual metamodel?

Comment: so it means the updations in ecore and xtext cant be done automatically? P.S. I am doing it for research purpose, actually. Satisfying my queries as I perceive xtext.

Comment: no. the wizard is just a starter point. i dont know anybody who uses the grammar created by it ootb